# odepack.error: The function and its Jacobian must be callable functions

Tags: python, odeint

odepack.error: The function and its Jacobian must be callable functions. How so i solve this?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from sympy import *
from scipy.integrate import odeint
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 
from scipy import optimize as opt 
import numpy as np 

x = Symbol('x')

def f(x):
    y =  100*(1-x**2)**2+(1-x)**2
    return y

def steepestDescent(f,x0,x):
    #y = np.zeros(100)
    for i in range(100):
        y = odeint(f,x0,x)
        x0 = x0-0.1*y;
    return x0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = np.linspace(-8,8,100)
    plt.plot(x,f(x),x,steepestDescent(f(x),2,x))
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Please post the actual error message including the traceback.

Comment: Can't see that you are actually calling a Jacobian anywhere in this code. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: My *guess* is that the problem is that you're calling `f(x)` in your calls to `plt()` and `steepestDescent()` rather than passing the function `f` as a parameter to these methods.